# C# ureachable code detected with if and do while

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            int x = 0;
            do
            {      
                if (false)
                {                 
                  Console.WriteLine("hold UP");
                }

                ++x;
                Console.WriteLine(x);

            } while (false);

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the question? You made a statement. You want to know where the unreachable code is? It's in the `if(false){` scope.

Comment: Please refer to the posting guidelines.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

What problem are you having? How can we reproduce them? What do you want as an expected outcome?

Answer (score 2):

That's the compiler warning you that some part of your code will never be executed. In your case it refers to this part.

```cs
if (false)
{                 
  Console.WriteLine("hold UP");
}
```

A similar thing would happen in cases like this:

```cs
void Test()
{
  return;
  // more code here.
}
//or
void Test2()
{
  while(true) //loop forever.
  { }
  // more code here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine("hold UP");` is unreachable because `if (false)` will *never* be `true`, thus the code in the following block can never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Andy is correct. For the code to run inside an If statement the conditions must be true. What you have there is a static condition of False, thus it will not enter into the If statement.